# JSON_parse unexpected end of data

Tags: json

i am tryig to receive json data from ajax call and i want to assign these response in javascript variable though its return correct data but also shows JSON.parse error in browser.

i have json encode response like:

```
{    
    "abcd.org": {
        "auction_id": "113885",
        "expiry_date_formatted": "2d 20h 52m",
        "expiry_date": "2014-10-13 15:48:17.498803",
        "buy_now_price": "6000",
        "current_bid_price": "500"
    }
}
```

Fetched using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "domain-check-ajax.html?dont_render_template=1&result=" + domain,
    timeout: 50000,
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg) {}
});
```

i am parsing it as below:

```
JSON.parse(msg, function (k, v){
      switch(k){
        case "auction_id":
          auction_id = v;
          break;
        case "buy_now_price":
         buy_now_price = v;
         break;
        case "current_bid_price":
         current_bid_price = v;
         break;
      }
});
```

but it showing me

```
**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data
[Break On This Error] JSON.parse(msg, function (k, v){**
```

Comment: Just created a JSFiddle and it appears to work here:
http://jsfiddle.net/o9y0x8o9/

Comment: Can you show the code for your AJAX call? It's possible the response has already been parsed.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
getJSON('URL', function(data) {

  alert('Your public IP address is: ' + data.ip);

}
```